# Solving a complex implicit equation on python

Tags: python, function

I have this function:

```
atanh((y/10^3)-3)-((10^(3)*y^(3)-11*10^(6)*y**2 + 3.93*10^(10)*y - 4.47*10^13)/((y - 2 * 10^3)*(y -4 * 10^3)^3))=3.49875*10^(-4)*t-atanh(3) + 0.3489583
```

(As you can see in the image).

[image: Function]

and I need it to return a y value (as a float), for a given time (t) value. I have to try the times t=0.1; t=2; t= 0,2.

I tried the fsolve function but I get an error message. This is what I did:

```
from cmath import atanh
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

t=1
def f(y,t):
    return atanh((y/10**3)-3)-((10**(3)*y**(3)-11*10**(6)*y**2 + 3.93*10**(10)*y - 4.47*10**13)/((y - 2 * 10**3)*(y -4 * 10**3)**3))-3.49875*10**(-4)*t+atanh(3) - 0.3489583

fsolve(f(y,t),1.9)
```

For which I got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a340e1c537e4> in <module>
      6     return atanh((y/10**3)-3)-((10**(3)*y**(3)-11*10**(6)*y**2 + 3.93*10**(10)*y - 4.47*10**13)/((y - 2 * 10**3)*(y -4 * 10**3)**3))-3.49875*10**(-4)*t+atanh(3) - 0.3489583
      7 
----> 8 fsolve(f(y,t),1.9)

<ipython-input-12-a340e1c537e4> in f(y, t)
      4 t=1
      5 def f(y,t):
----> 6     return cmath.atanh((y/10**3)-3)-((10**(3)*y**(3)-11*10**(6)*y**2 + 3.93*10**(10)*y - 4.47*10**13)/((y - 2 * 10**3)*(y -4 * 10**3)**3))-3.49875*10**(-4)*t+cmath.atanh(3) - 0.3489583
      7 
      8 fsolve(f(y,t),1.9)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in __complex__(self)
    283         result = self.evalf()
    284         re, im = result.as_real_imag()
--> 285         return complex(float(re), float(im))
    286 
    287     def __ge__(self, other):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in __float__(self)
    278         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    279             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
--> 280         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
    281 
    282     def __complex__(self):

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

What I was hoping to get on the output was y as a real number .
I did search for other similar questions on this site but I still couldn't solve this problem .

Comment: It seems that is not a function, but an equality

Comment: Its a implicit function. Which means I can't really isolate the x or the t.

Comment: Also, with the way you import `from cmath import atanh`, you would call it by just stating `atanh()`

Comment: @Kit. I deleted the t value and I still get the same error

Comment: Calling it a function of both y and t. I'm not sure if I'm right by doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sibling answer shows the way to pass the extra parameter `t` to `f`.
But, then you run into another problem. The equation seems to be complex, while `fsolve` only works for real functions.

One way to tackle these, is `mpmath`, Python's multiprecision library. `mpmath` has a function `findroot` that also works for complex numbers. Note that due to the multiprecision, it can be much slower than other libraries. I don't directly see a simple way to pass the `t` parameter, so I made use of a `lambda` function:

```py
from mpmath import findroot, atanh

def f(y,t):
    return atanh((y/10**3)-3)-((10**(3)*y**(3)-11*10**(6)*y**2 + 3.93*10**(10)*y - 4.47*10**13)/((y - 2 * 10**3)*(y -4 * 10**3)**3))-3.49875*10**(-4)*t+atanh(3) - 0.3489583

y0 = 1.9
for t in (0.1, 2, 0.2):
    ans = findroot(lambda y: f(y,t), y0)
    print(f'f({ans}, {t}) = {y0}')
```

output:

```
f((-52.8736406772712 + 1.4361714816895e-17j), 0.1) = 1.9
f((89.2356161023805 + 1.85315086887834e-19j), 2) = 1.9
f((-44.2974817249413 + 5.70332910817907e-18j), 0.2) = 1.9
```

I also tried to visualize the function. It seems that the real part is almost linearly dependent on t, while the imaginary part is extremely small. For some values of t, `findroot` doesn't find a solution within its default tolerance. I just skipped these t values. You might want to experiment with tolerances and available solvers for `findroot`.

Here are the code and the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000
ts = np.linspace(0, 3, N)
real = np.zeros(N)
imag = np.zeros(N)
for i, t in enumerate(ts):
    try:
        ans = findroot(lambda y: f(y, t), y0)
    except:
        print("no solution at", t)
        pass # just use the previous value of ans
    real[i], imag[i] = ans.real, ans.imag

#plt.plot(real, imag, 'b', lw=1)
scat = plt.scatter(real, imag, c=ts, s=5)
plt.ylim((min(imag), max(imag)))
plt.xlabel('real axis')
plt.ylabel('imaginary axis')
plt.title('y values for f(y,t)=1.9, t=[0, 3]', fontsize=13)
plt.colorbar(scat, label='t values')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of the roots]

Comment: Thank you so much ! This was exactly it! :)